# How to change the default YEDIS RPC port for YugaByte-DB?

Tags: yugabytedb

I am setting up a YugaByte cluster , but I already have Redis using port 6379. How to change the YEDIS port to another ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the flag `--redis_proxy_bind_address=<ip address>:<new port>` to the `yb-tserver` process in order to change the default port for YEDIS.